# Getting the certain Attribute in nested XML nodes using c#

Tags: c#, xml, nodes

I have the XML from the file animals.XML. how can i get the value dog cat and bird. Im new with xml and c# thanks

```
<config>
   <settingA>
   <settingA/>

   <settingB>
       <add key="as" val="dog"/>
       <add key="bd" val="cat"/>
       <add key="da" val="bird"/>
   <settingB/>

   <settingC>
   <settingC/>
<config/>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? There are many tutorials and questions about this

Answer (score 0):

//load the XML in memory from a document or other ways

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("");
var values = doc.Descendants("settingB");
foreach( var value in values )
  {
     Console.WriteLine( value.Value );
  }
Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

I am also isn't professional, but I think something like this should works.

```
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.Load("");// load from file for example
foreach(XmlNode node in xml.DocumentElement["settingB"].ChildNodes){
    Console.WriteLine(node.Attributes["val"].Value);
}
Console.ReadLine();
```